# Spring Boot authentication across apps

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

If I have multiple Spring Boot apps running that both import their authentication manager from the same source, how can I login to one app and then be able to access the second app without having to login again?

This is a Maven multi module project where the security config is contained in a shared module that each other module depends on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even though they are importing the same authentication manager if these are separate apps running in separate jvms you will need something that they can all talk to.

I would suggest using [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas). With CAS when a user needs to login they will be redirected to cas for a login screen. After successfully logging in they will be redirected to your application. If the user is already logged in to CAS when redirected to it they will be immediately redirected to the app with out the user even noticing. There is [some Spring Security documentation for using CAS](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#cas-sample) However I will warn you it is not trivial to setup.

The other option I might suggest is Open ID. Which again there is [Spring Security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#openid-sample) for it however I have no experience with it.